# System.NullReferenceException message when I created the object?

Tags: c#

It's highlighting my object `c` and saying it's null even though I created the object on the previous line.  I'm referring to this line below.

```
c.wm.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Here is the whole thing:

```
public class dict
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> wm;
    public dict()
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> wm = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
}    

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dict c = new dict();    
            c.wm.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the type from the `wm` declaration in your constructor. You are instantiating a new variable called `wm` rather that instantiating the property on the class.

```
public dict()
{
    wm = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
}
```

Even better, as per Dai's comment, use the `this` keyword to explicitly specify the class property.

```
public dict()
{
    this.wm = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use the disambiguating `this` keyword to explicitly specify the field instead of a local.

Comment: @Dai, indeed. Although not really necessary in this case as it is a parameterless constructor, I've added it in for completeness.